# How can I make Laravel eloquent relationship with multiple tables?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationship, eloquent-relationship

I am trying to make 3 tables relationship like this,

```
users
    id
    name
roles
    id
    name
companies
    id
    name
company_role_user
    user_id
    role_id
    company_id
```

Relationships in **User.php** model

```
public function companies() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Company::class, 'company_role_user', 'user_id', 'company_id');
}

public function roles() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class, 'company_role_user', 'user_id', 'role_id');
}

public function role() {
    // relationship to get role of specific company
}
```

Relationships in **Company.php** model

```
public function users() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'company_role_user', 'company_id', 'user_id');
}

public function roles() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class, 'company_role_user', 'company_id', 'role_id');
}

public function role() {
    // relationship to get role of specific user
}
```

I want to get user role for specific company like this

```
User::find(1)->companies[0]->role->name
```

or

```
Company::find(1)->users[0]->role->name
```

Comment: Companies and Users has many `Roles`, you cant get only 1 role like the example provided `Company::find(1)->users[0]->role->name`

Comment: Companies and Users individually has many Roles. But for a specific Company and a specific User, there has only one role. Because company_role_user table has no duplicate row entry. @Kloshar4o

Comment: I have no problem if I get array inside single item. I can get this like this, 
Company::find(1)->users[0]->role[0]->name

Comment: It looks like you are trying to connect 3 tables "many to many", if you can, you should consider simplifying this, many to many tables are rarely necessary, make it simpler:  
User belongsTo Company,  
Company hasMany User,  
User hasMany Role,  
so you could do something like
User::find(1)->roles,  
Company::find(1)->user->roles  
  
Why should companies has roles?

Comment: Companies shouldn't have roles. But companies user has a role. For example, user1 is an admin of company1, user1 is a member of company2, user2 is a member of company1. Here admin and member are roles. how can I get this?

Answer (score 0):

If you have users

```
users
– id
– name
```

and you want them to have many to many relation with companies, you should do:

```
companies
– id
– name

user_companies
– user_id
– company_id
```

And for your roles, (many to many) you can do the same:

```
roles
 - id
 - name

user_roles
 - user_id
 - role_id
```

You are trying to make many to many 3 tables, when you should be doing it with 2 tables.
Even if you manage, it would be very complicated and confusing.
You should consider which tables should be related to roles, companies should have roles, or users should have roles, you dont need them both to have roles

Comment: If I ask you User1 has a role Admin of which company? How can you find it according to your database design?

Answer (score 0):

Your schema looks correct but your model definitions/relations can use a junction/pivot model `CompanyRoleUser` which will relate these 3 relations as many-to-one/belongsTo and one-to-many/hasMany from Company/Role/User.

```
class Company extends Model
{
    public function companyRoleUser()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(CompanyRoleUser::class, 'id', 'company_id');
    }
}

class Role extends Model
{
    public function companyRoleUser()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(CompanyRoleUser::class, 'id', 'role_id');
    }
}

class User extends Model
{
    public function companyRoleUser()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(CompanyRoleUser::class, 'id', 'user_id');
    }
}

class CompanyRoleUser extends Model
{
    public function company()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Discipline::class, 'id', 'company_id');
    }
    public function role()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Speciality::class, 'id', 'role_id');
    }
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class ,'id','user_id');
    }
}
```

Now you can apply different type of filters for your data like

Fetch users for company A id = 1 with admin role id = 2

```
User::whereHas('companyRoleUser.company', function ($query) use ($company_id) {
       $query->where('id', $company_id);
     })->whereHas('companyRoleUser.role', function ($query) use ($role_id) {
       $query->where('id', $role_id);
     });
```

Or

```
User::whereHas('companyRoleUser', function ($query) use ($company_id) {
       $query->where('company_id', $company_id)
             ->where('role_id', $role_id);
     });
```

Fetch companies with `$user_id` and `$role_id`

```
Company::whereHas('companyRoleUser', function ($query) use ($user_id) {
       $query->where('user_id', $user_id)
             ->where('role_id', $role_id);
     });
```